# Pine Script: Possible to use "Fill" function without calling on two plots

Tags: pine-script

Possible to use "Fill" function without calling on two plots

```
cloudline1 = ema(src, length1)
        cloudline2 = ema(src, length2)


        cloudcolour = cloudline1 >= cloudline2 ? green : red


        mashortline = plot(cloudline1, color = #ffffff, linewidth = 2, title = "Cloud Length 1")
        mamidline = plot(cloudline2, color = #ffffff, linewidth = 2, title = "Cloud Length 2")


      Filler = fill(mashortline, mamidline, color = cloudcolour, transp = 45, title = "Cloud")
```

can i use something like

"Filler = fill(cloudline1, cloudline2, color = cloudcolour, transp = 45, title = "Cloud")"

i dont want to plot out the ema's

ive tried this yet i keep getting "cannot call fill with arguments"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`plot` function has an argument named `display`.

> display (const integer) Controls where the plot is displayed. Possible
>   values are: display.none, display.all. Default is display.all

You can call `plot()` with `display=display.none`, then it will not plot the ema lines by default. You can enable it in the indicator settings later on, if you want.

```
mashortline = plot(cloudline1, color = color.orange, linewidth = 2, title = "Cloud Length 1", display=display.none)
mamidline = plot(cloudline2, color = color.blue, linewidth = 2, title = "Cloud Length 2", display=display.none)
fill(mashortline, mamidline, color = cloudcolour, transp = 45, title = "Cloud")
```

Note that, I am using orange and blue colors for the ema lines and you shouldn't be able to see those lines by default when you call `plot()`with `display=display.none`.